# lavaan warning: The variance-covariance matrix of the estimated parameters (vcov) does not appear to be positive definite

Tags: r, structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor, lavaan

I'm trying to estimate the following CFA model with the lavaan package and get the warning: The variance-covariance matrix of the estimated parameters (vcov) does not appear to be positive definite! The smallest eigenvalue (= -2.941160e-15) is smaller than zero. This may be a symptom that the model is not identified.

```
FEMusiK.model <-   '#8 Faktoren
                    Unterhaltung =~ FEMusiK1 + FEMusiK2 + FEMusiK3 + FEMusiK4
                    Erholung =~ FEMusiK5 + FEMusiK6 + FEMusiK7 + FEMusiK8 + FEMusiK9 + FEMusiK10 + FEMusiK11
                    sEmpfindungen =~ FEMusiK12 + FEMusiK13 + FEMusiK14 + FEMusiK15 + FEMusiK16 + FEMusiK17 + FEMusiK18
                    Ablenkung =~ FEMusiK19 + FEMusiK20 + FEMusiK21 + FEMusiK22 + FEMusiK23
                    Entladung =~ FEMusiK24 + FEMusiK25 + FEMusiK26 + FEMusiK27 + FEMusiK28 + FEMusiK29
                    mArbeit =~ FEMusiK30 + FEMusiK31 + FEMusiK32 + FEMusiK33 + FEMusiK34
                    Trost =~ FEMusiK35 + FEMusiK36 + FEMusiK37 + FEMusiK38 + FEMusiK39 + FEMusiK40
                    Immersion =~ FEMusiK41 + FEMusiK42 + FEMusiK43 + FEMusiK44 + FEMusiK45
                    
                    #Faktor 2. Ordnung                  
                    FEMusiK_global =~ Unterhaltung + Erholung + sEmpfindungen + Ablenkung + Entladung + mArbeit + Trost + Immersion'

FEMusiK.model.fit <- cfa(FEMusiK.model, data=Data, estimator="MLR", missing="FIML")
summary(FEMusiK.model.fit, fit.measures=TRUE, standardized=TRUE)
```

I have 78 observations and 45 Variables. My data is nonnormal so I used the MLR estimator.

I read in different forums, that this warning can be ignored, but I'm not sure about it. What does it exactly mean and what can I do about it? How can I find out, where the problem is?

Comment: The small number of observations might be an issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/69930089/9524424

Comment: What is machine epsilon for your computer? If it's on the order of $10^{-15},$ you may simply be running into roundoff error.